# ElasticSearch:filtering documents based on field length?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is there a way to filter ElasticSearch documents based on the length of a specific field?

For instance, I have a bunch of documents with the field "body", and I only want to return results where the number of characters in body is > 1000. Is there a way to do this in ES without having to add an extra column with the length in the index?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the script filter, like this:

```
"filtered" : {
    "query" : {
        ...
    }, 
    "filter" : {
        "script" : {
            "script" : "doc['body'].length > 1000"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Sorry, meant to reference [the query DSL guide on script filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html)

Comment: The [documentation for Elasticsearch 2.1](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html) doesn't mention a `.length` field, does this still work?

Comment: Presumably, if you explicitly enable scripting support this would still work (scripting was disabled by default in v1.4 I believe). Groovy scripting is now used rather than MVEL, so you'll probably want to check into this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023233/elasticsearch-statistical-facet-on-length-of-string-field mentions you can use `"script" : "doc['body'].value.length()"` which worked for me on 1.7.5

Comment: link is bad i think

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom tokenizer and use it in a multifields property as in the following:

```
PUT test_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "character_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "character_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "character_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "mappings": {
    "person": {
      "properties": {
        "name": { 
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": { 
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "words_count": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "length": { 
              "type": "token_count",
              "analyzer": "character_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test_index/person/1
{
  "name": "John Smith"
}

PUT test_index/person/2
{
  "name": "Rachel Alice Williams"
}

GET test_index/person/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "name.length": 10
    }
  }
}
```