# ElasticSearch - Statistical facet on length of string field

Tags: elasticsearch, facet

I would like to retrieve data about a string field like the min, max and average length (by counting the number of characters inside the string). My issue is that [aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) can only be used for numeric fields. Besides, I tried it using a simple statistical facet,

```
 "query":{
      "match_all": {}
  }, 
 "facets":{
      "stat1":{
           "statistical":{
               "field":"title"}
               }
          }
```

but I get shard failures and SearchPhaseExecutionException. When trying with a script field the error returned is an OutOfMemoryError:

```
  "query":{
       "match_all": {}
   }, 
  "script_fields":{
       "test1":{"script": "doc[\"title\"].value" }
   }
```

Is it possible to retrive such data about a simple "title" string field using CURL? Thank you!

Comment: yes, you can run scripts on your fields http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html#search-request-script-fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually tried the following, but I believe it should work.

First some useful doc-references:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-statistical-facet.html.

> In order to implement the statistical facet, the relevant field values
>   are loaded into memory from the index. This means that per shard,
>   there should be enough memory to contain them. Since by default,
>   dynamic introduced types are long and double, one option to reduce the
>   memory footprint is to explicitly set the types for the relevant
>   fields to either short, integer, or float when possible.

I'm not sure directly how to set the type of the script-field to 'short' which is probably what you want. to reduce memory. it SHOULD be possible though.

ALSO: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html

> It’s important to understand the difference between
>   doc['my_field'].value and _source.my_field. The first, using the doc
>   keyword, will cause the terms for that field to be loaded to memory
>   (cached), which will result in faster execution, but more memory
>   consumption. Also, the doc[...] notation only allows for simple valued
>   fields (can’t return a json object from it) and make sense only on
>   non-analyzed or single term based fields.

So ALTERNATIVE: would be to use `_source` instead of `doc` which would not cache the lengths.

Gives:

```
    {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "facets" : {
            "stat1" : {
                "statistical" : {
                    "script" : "doc['title'].value.length()
                    //"script" : "_source.title.length() //ALTERNATIVE which isn't cached
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the very useful insights! I tried both versions, the first one crashes with OutOfMemoryException, while the second alternative gives me SearchPhraseExecutionException - PropertyAccessException - could not access length.

Comment: Oh, I found out! I should have used length(). It works like a charm now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Dan you update the answer with the length(), is nice for people reading this question/answer.

Comment: One more question though: how can I sort these results desc and not see only the top 10 displayed? What I need are actually statistics like min length, max length and average length.

Comment: changed to `length()` as per comment.

Comment: @Crista23: well statistical facet should give you that. (see: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-statistical-facet.html) NOt having an install here, but the output should show stuff like `min, max, mean, avg, std-dev`